# How can I convert first page of PDF to JPG or PNG in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wand

I have a pdf with some text and some images. I want to covert the first page of this document to a image file, preferable jpg or png, but tiff will also work. I have tried using Wand, but i get this error:

```
wand.exceptions.BlobError: unable to open image `myfile.pdf'(changing myfile.py to the actual name): No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2735
  Exception ignored in: <bound method Image.__del__ of <wand.image.Image: (empty)>>
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wand/resource.py", line 232, in __del__
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wand/image.py", line 2767, in destroy
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

I have also tried to use ghostscript and pdf2img, also those without any luck.

What is the best way to convert .pdf to .jpg or .png in Python3?

Comment: With Ghostscript, "gs -sDEVICE=png16m -o out.png -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 <input.pdf>". Try that from the command shell (if on Windows, use gswin32c or gswin64c depending on whether you installed the 32 or 64 bit version). If that doesn't work, I'll need to see the PDF file. If it does then all you need to do is run that from Python.

Comment: Do those other tools also say they cannot find the file? Do you *have* a PDF file named "myfile.pdf" in the same folder as you are executing this command? Should the program otherwise be able to locate this file? Does it work with other PDFs?

Comment: @usr2564301 Yes, I have the file, and when I use PyPDF2 to save the first page as a new pdf.